# Closing Event and Catel's MessageService, can't Cancel

Tags: c#, wpf, catel

I'm using an ExitCommand to close the application from Menu->Exit, I've tried to implement the same exit behavior when user click on X

I've defined this in my XAML

```
<catel:Window x:Class="IF.Tesoreria.Client.WPF.Views.ShellView"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com"
          xmlns:view="clr-namespace:IF.Tesoreria.Client.WPF.Views"
          xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
          Icon="../Media/threasure.gif" Height="500" Width="800" >
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <catel:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"  PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid>
<!--omiss-->
```

And in the ViewModel I've used the following command

```
   public Command<CancelEventArgs> ExitCommand { get; private set; }

   #region CTor
    public ShellViewModel( IDynamicContainer dynamicContainer, IViewModelFactory viewModelFactory)
    {
        this.dynamicContainer = dynamicContainer;
        this.viewModelFactory = viewModelFactory;

        ShowInfoCommand = new Command(ShowInfoCommandExecute);
        ExitCommand = new Command<CancelEventArgs>(OnExitCommandExecute);
    }
    #endregion

private void OnExitCommandExecute(CancelEventArgs args)
    {
        var res = MessageBox.Show(Properties.Resources.DIALOG_EXIT, Properties.Resources.DIALOG_EXIT_CAPTION,MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        //var res = messageService.Show(Properties.Resources.DIALOG_EXIT, Properties.Resources.DIALOG_EXIT_CAPTION,
        //      MessageButton.YesNo, MessageImage.Question);

        if (res == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            ICloseApplicationService closeApplicationService = this.GetServiceLocator().ResolveType<ICloseApplicationService>();
            closeApplicationService.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            args.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

If I use the MessageBox I'm able to cancel the closing event (setting args.Cancel = true). Otherwise if I use the IMessageService, when I get the result from Show it's too late

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The IMessageService in Catel is async. We are considering to implement this in a different way. In the meantime, use INavigationService.ClosingApplication event.

Comment: This won't fix the problem when I ask the user if he wants to close since even if I put the messageService.Show in the ClosingApplication event I'll got the application to be closed since it's async again